# ¿Como retornar una lista de otra clase en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

estoy tratando de retornar una lista desde otro script de Python, desde una clase llamada Woodworth.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      
class Woodworth():
      def __init__(self,dis_oidos):
            self.dis_oidos = dis_oidos
            a = dis_oidos/2 #Radio de la cabeza
            c = 343 #Velocidad del sonido
            azimuth1 = np.arange(0,np.pi/2,np.pi/36)
            azimuth2 = np.arange(np.pi/2,np.pi,np.pi/36)
            itd1 = azimuth1+np.sin(azimuth1)
            ITD1 = (a/c)*itd1
            itd2 = np.pi-azimuth2+np.sin(azimuth2)
            ITD2 = (a/c)*itd2
            ITD1 = ITD1.tolist()
            ITD2 = ITD2.tolist()
            ITD = []
            azimuth =[]
            for i in range(len(ITD1)):
                  x = ITD1[i]
                  ITD.append(x)
            for i in range(len(ITD2)):
                  x = ITD2[i]
                  ITD.append(x)
            for i in range(len(azimuth1)):
                  x = azimuth1[i]
                  azimuth.append(x)
            for i in range(len(azimuth2)):
                  x = azimuth2[i]
                  azimuth.append(x)
            j = len(azimuth)
            y = azimuth[j-1]+np.pi/36
            azimuth.append(y)
            ITD.append(0)
            return list(ITD)
```

Esta es mi clase, la estoy importando desde el otro script pero me sale el siguiente error,     `ITD = wd.Woodworth(19.1) TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'list'`

Este es el código donde estoy llamando la clase

```
import woodworth as wd

x=19.1
ITD = wd.Woodworth(19.1)
print(ITD)
```

No se si deba crear la lista también en el código 2, ya lo intente pero aún así me sigue botando el mismo error. Estuve averiguando y me decía que tiene que ver con **init**() de la clase, pero la verdad no estoy seguro como hacer.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Parece ser que no necesitas que `Woodworth` sea una clase, sino que sea una función. Claramente tienes entradas (`dis_oidos`), procesamientos y salida (`ITD`). Es un candidato genial para ser una función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eso no se puede en python, haz un metodo to list(). algo asi

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.__a = a
        self.__b = b
    def to_list(self):
        a =[]
        a.append(self.__a)
        a.append(self.__b)
        return a
obj = MyClass(5, 6)
print(obj.to_list())
```

Comment: Vale muchas gracias